# Merging 2 Dataframes into 1 Resultant Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with a DateTimeIndex holding timeseries data. I, then read a sql table into another dataframe.

DF-A:

```
                     A  B  C
2019-09-10 00:00:00  0  0  0
2019-09-11 00:00:00  0  0  0
2019-09-12 00:00:00  0  8  9
```

DF-B:

```
                     A  B  C
2019-09-10 00:00:00  1  2  3
2019-09-11 00:00:00  4  5  6
2019-09-12 00:00:00  7  NaN  0
```

What I want to do, is combine the values of the cells within the dataframe. So the results would be

```
                     A  B  C
2019-09-10 00:00:00  1  2  3
2019-09-11 00:00:00  4  5  6
2019-09-12 00:00:00  7  8  9
```

I could do this 1 of 2 ways. Either take the higher number of the cell, or add them together. there always will be either a value, or a 0.

It looks like append, combine, or join/merge doesn't really have a way to do this natively.

Is there a way to do this without iterating through the rows?

Comment: `DFA.fillna(0) + DFB.fillna(0)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can using `add` with `fill_value`

```
df1=df1.add(df2,fill_value=0)
df1
                    A    B  C
2019-09-100:00:00   1  2.0  3
2019-09-1100:00:00  4  5.0  6
2019-09-1200:00:00  7  8.0  9
```